# Tween Engine library problems on Android libgdx project

Tags: libgdx, tween

This is the same problem I have read and no useful answer found,
I have libgdx, and tween engine progect,i'm working with eclipse,
I use this tutorial to install tween engine [Uneversal Tween Engine](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine)

all ok, no errors, I use FileTree Dependency Method, the program run on desktop but not on android, there is no erros on the code,I

I import the project with Android studio, and the erros are

**Error:(14, 33) error: package aurelienribon.tweenengine does not exist**

**Error:(25, 10) error: cannot find symbol class TweenManager**
etc...

my project is at 
C:\NovelaGrafica\codigoFonte

my tween jar files are located at

C:\NovelaGrafica\codigoFonte\libs\tween-engine-api-6.3.3

the main problens is on using the tween library,
WHAT CAN I DO,??? I have spend day looking for answers but nothing works
I'm using windows 10, eclipse Mars and android studio

HELP PLEASE!..........:(

Answer (score 0):

I Finaly got it I just folow that tutorial [Universal-Tween-Engine](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine)

with a difrence, at the end I didnt use gradlew --refresh-dependencies I use, and that is the importante point  **gradlew.bat eclipse**  I'm using windows10 if you are using linux I think is somethin similar probably **./gradlew eclipse**

them I **Close the eclipse project and import it again**, this is important too

I spend 2 day for finding a solution to this ....